# How to call continues Ajax requests in background without disturbing front-end page

Tags: ajax, reactjs

I want to develop a report page with continues ajax requests which is retrieves a bunch of record sets for each call to complete the entire report,
i.e ,
i want to display a 1000 of student records and for retrieving whole 1000 records makes more loading time which is need to be avoided. so i just created a loop of ajax requests which fetch 100 records for each request. In this case the browser holds until the total of 1000 records displays ...i want to avoid this i want to run the ajax requests in background and it not should disturb or hold the browser to see the first 100 records..

```
   while( loop until the whole records retrived ){
    $.ajax({
    url: "/erp/reports/json/student_report/",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {class_id : id},
    success: function (json) { // retrieve 100 records  } 
    });
  }
```

Or tell me that do i approached wrong way can i achieve this using react is possible?

thanks in advance

Comment: if you use while loop the *event loop* will wait for the while loop to finish its execution so the page will not render anything. if you want to fire ajax request one after another use call the function again from the success callback

Comment: In that case the browser wont hold isnt it? @NijeeshJoshy

Comment: yes, since the ajax call doesn't directly block the render. the browser will have enough time between the calls to do its "operations".  (I am overly simplifying things here.).

Comment: watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ). You will understand why your while loop blocked the event que.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will make sure you call the next ajax request right after the first one finishes.

```
function fetchRecords(id){
     $.ajax({
        url: "/erp/reports/json/student_report/",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {class_id : id},
        success: function (json) {
        // retrieve 100 records 
        // DO WHAT EVER YOU WANNA DO HERE
         if(! the whole records retrived )
           fetchRecords(id)
        } 
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a recursive function and javascript timeout.
That is, you make a function for ajax, then call the function by timeout recursively.
Please take a look my sample code.
This is a function to get all records more than 1000 by 100 records per page.
It should be refined as you wants

```
function  clickedOrder() {
    orderPageIndex = 0;
    orderCnt = 0;
    importOrder();
}

function importOrder() {
    orderPageIndex++;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: './order.php',
        async: false,
        data: {pageIndex: orderPageIndex, orderCount: orderCnt},
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            if (result.indexOf("OK") == 0 || result.indexOf("Zero") == 0) {
                alert("imported successfully");
            } else if (result.indexOf("ERROR") == 0) {
                alert("Import Failed" + result);
            } else if (result.indexOf("Order")==0) {
                var strCnt = result.substring(result.indexOf(":") + 1);
                orderCnt += strCnt*1;
                startOrderTimer();
            } else {
                alert("Import Failed" + result);
            }
        },
        error:function(error){
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}

function startOrderTimer () {
    setTimeout(stopOrderTimer,100);
}

function stopOrderTimer () {
    importOrder();
}
```